# How to tell what PPA my Linux Mint install is downloading docker.io from

Tags: linux-mint, docker, ppa

I'm going down a rabid hole and realize downloading docker-ce instead of docker.io is probably better, but was curious to see when docker.io was last updated. I believe I've tracked it down to here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io However, I'm unsure how to tell which one it would install.

The Lunar Lobster

The Kinetic Kuda

etc.

Is there a command I can run on Linux Mint which would direct me to where my system retrieves install packages from?

How would I determine which one/version of a particular package it would install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apt policy` command will tell you both. From a Debian system:

```
$ apt policy docker.io
docker.io:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 20.10.5+dfsg1-1+deb11u2
  Version table:
     20.10.23+dfsg1-1 100
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
        100 http://deb.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
     20.10.5+dfsg1-1+deb11u2 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
```

You will get similar output on Mint, with different versions and repositories. The “Candidate” line will tell you which version would be installed by `apt install docker.io`, and the lines below that will tell you which repositories would be used for the various versions accessible from your system.